# Materializecss datepicker not working

Tags: datepicker, material-design, materialize

I am using `materializecss` for the first time in my web application and
I am struggling with **datepicker**. It is not  working at all.

I imported **materialize.css** and **js** file and use the code

```
<div>
 <input type="date"  class="datepicker" />
</div>
```

and added **script** code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();


    window.picker = $('.datepicker').pickadate({

        selectYears: 16, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });



});
```

but nothing worked, it shows a disabled text box.

Also I want to know how to add timepicker in `materializecss`?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. My problem was solved with downgrading jquery to 2.1.4. It seems, that on some reason the datetimepicker and jquery 2.2.1 are not working together.

cheers
Thomas

Comment: Same is true with jquery-2.1.1.min.js (the version they use in the starter template. Just use version 2.1.4 as suggested by @Thomas

Answer (score 6):

First to know, you need to check the version of your Materialize css and javascript version, also don't forget to check jquery version and use the initialization code in your custom init javascript.

**check my code in init.js for initialization, CSS and JS Materialize via cdn**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('.modal').modal();
    //this are my init
    $('#dtp').datepicker();
    $('#dtp').setDate(new Date());
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- this is my CSS via cdn -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <form class="col s12 m6 card">
        <div class="row center">
          <h4>Materialize DateTime Picker</h4>
          <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
            <input id="dtp" type="text" class="datepicker">
            <label for="dtp">Birthday</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- this is my JS via cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check the documentation from [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) website, it is always helpful for programmers like me.
Hope this answer help you

**Try to run my Code Snippet**

Comment: It's a little bit strange: when I'm dowloading the starter template of materializecss, the datepicker doesn't work. I always get the error `datepicker is not a function`. When I use your code from above, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="idate" type="text"  name="idate" class="datepicker" >
            <label for="idate">Issue Date</label>
          </div>
        </div>


$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true,// Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
});
```